# SQL: Joining table A and table B when rows may be missing in TABLE B

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to join data from two table A, and B on a timestamp. I ideally want every row of tableA that meet the unitCode and time constraints, and if there is an associated row in tableB then join it, otherwise assume the coloumns from table B are attached but are null or empty.

*Assume TableA looks something like this:*

**id | timestamp | itemA1 | itemA2 | itemA3**

*and TableB looks somthing like this:*

**id | timestamp | itemB1 | itemB2**

so data might look like this:

- timestamp | itemA1 | itemA2 | itemA3 | itemB1 | itemB2
- [datetime]| 10     | 11     | 40     | 26     | 12
- [datetime]| 10     | 11     | 40     | 26     | 12
- [datetime]| 10     | 11     | 40     | null   | null
- [datetime]| 10     | 11     | 40     | 26     | 12
- [datetime]| 10     | 11     | 40     | null   | null

Currently I'm using this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM tableB) AS b
ON (a.timestamp = b.timestamp)
WHERE b.unitCode = 'CODE' AND b.timestamp BETWEEN 'STARTDATETIME' AND 'ENDDATETIME' ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC`
```

but it only makes rows out of the instances where there is a corresponding tableB for a given tableA.

Comment: You need an outer join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` takes all records on the left side of the condition statement, and all those for which it applies on the right. However, you need to be careful in your `WHERE` clause, because if it has a value restriction on your right table (in your case table 'b') then it will still exclude those rows.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tableB) AS b
ON (a.timestamp = b.timestamp)
WHERE b.unitCode = 'CODE' AND b.timestamp BETWEEN 'STARTDATETIME' AND 'ENDDATETIME' ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC`
```

`LEFT JOIN` reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

`JOIN` graphic
[image]

As @Ike pointed out, your query could be corrected to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA AS a 
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b
    ON a.timestamp = b.timestamp
    AND b.unitCode = 'CODE' 
    AND b.timestamp BETWEEN 'STARTDATETIME' AND 'ENDDATETIME'
ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC`
```

Since as I mentioned earlier, if the conditions were in the `WHERE` clause, it would exclude the concept of the `LEFT JOIN` and therefore all rows with `NULL` values (because it didn't meet the criteria for table b) would be excluded.

To address your comment, if you added `WHERE` clauses, I would suggest (based on what I understand of your goal) only having the conditions affect tableA and have all the conditions for tableB be in the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA AS a 
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b
    ON a.timestamp = b.timestamp
    AND b.unitCode = 'CODE' 
    AND b.timestamp BETWEEN 'STARTDATETIME' AND 'ENDDATETIME'
WHERE
    a.timestamp BETWEEN 'STARTDATETIME' AND 'ENDDATETIME'
ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC`
```

Now, if the `a.timestamp` condition is what you're looking for, then the condition for tableB in the `LEFT JOIN` is redundant because we already know that the timestamps in tableB must match a corresponding one in tableA.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` is appropriate here, but the query also needs some other changes: 1) get rid of the unnecessary sub-query on tableB 2) move the filtering criteria on tableB from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause to preserve the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Please don't use (nor promote the use of) 'SELECT *'

Comment: Thanks @KeithChason, this almost got me there - however, I'm not sure if it's due to me using mariaDB but the query doesn't seem to be respecting the unit_code and time constraints. It gives me all tableA (including all unitCodes and not respecting the time constraint). Is there something missing? brackets possibly? or a WHERE clause?

Comment: @Strawberry even if I always need all the values?

Comment: @RobotBox2000 The situation cannot occur.

Comment: Correct, there's nothing restricting tableA currently. From what you had originally, the two conditions in the `WHERE` clause both pertained to tableB. If you wanted to add restrictions to tableA, you could do that with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @KeithChason yea I'm looking to have the same constraints run on both tables - sorry my sql syntax is pretty weak... what might that look like?

Comment: Nice, that's it - minus one last thing.. it seems when I do the join the tables i wind up with two identical timestamp columns - is it possible to remove one of them?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what @Strawberry was talking about with avoiding `SELECT * FROM`, you should list the columns you want as `SELECT a.column1, b.column2... FROM...`

Comment: Ahhh... and it all comes full circle - thanks you two!!